# Can any one solve it unable to fill null value using .replace or .fillna?

Tags: python, debugging

[image]

I tried multiple time to execute the code but I'm unable to fill the null value.

Comment: Please post text and code as text/code and NOT AS IMAGE!

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly, you are already doing it right. One thing you forgot is to save the modified df.

EDIT:
If you want to use fillna instead of replace:

```
df["new"] = df["Price"].fillna(mean)
```

or

```
df["new"] = df["Price"].replace(np.nan, mean)
```

Documentation Link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

here they say near Return:

> Object after replacement or None if inplace=True.

Comment: when i use `df['Price] = code` all value converts to null and null value replace with mean.